# $D^n\times D^m\cong D^{n+m}$?

Tags: general-topology, circles

Let $D^n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||\le 1\}$ the unit closed ball in dimension $n$, and $I=D^1=[0,1]$.

We have $D^1\times D^1=I\times I\cong D^2$.

Is it true that

$$D^n\times D^m\cong D^{n+m}$$

for all $n,m\ge 0$ ? If so, where does the homeomorphism comes from ?

Comment: Yes. Simply find a homeomorphism $D^n \cong I^n$ for each $n$, and then it's obvious...

Comment: @ZhenLin Then the question would be how does $D^n\cong I^n$ ?

Comment: Indeed, and the answer is yes, because both are homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. See [Every open ball of a normed vector space $E$ its homeomorph to the entire space $E$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756987/every-open-ball-of-a-normed-vector-space-e-its-homeomorph-to-the-entire-space)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the unit disk inside the cube $[-1,1] \times \ldots \times [-1,1]$ (with $n$-factors). Then project radially.

Comment: Yeah, that's the intuition, I get it. But can you kindly provide an explicit function that is an explicit expression?