# Spheres in different normed vector spaces are homeomorphics

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $(V,||\cdot||_{V})$ and $(W,||\cdot||_{W})$ be two normed vector spaces with the same finite dimension. Is it true that the spheres
$$
\{v \in V : ||v||_{V} = 1\}\text{ and }\{w \in W : ||w||_{W} = 1\}
$$
are homeomorphics?  It is pretty easy to show that the repectives open balls centered in  origem in $V$ and $W$ are homeomorphics. One only has to show that the open balls in $V$ and $W$ are homeomorphic to $V$ and $W$, respectivlly and use the fact that $V$ and $W$ are isomorphics. Here has a discussion about it:
[Every open ball of a normed vector space $E$ its homeomorph to the entire space $E$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756987/every-open-ball-of-a-normed-vector-space-e-its-homeomorph-to-the-entire-space).

However to conclude the spheres are also homeomorphics seems to be more delicate.

Comment: But how to guarantee there's always a norm preserving map between those spaces? If the spaces were Hilbert spaces I know  how to proceed. But in fact I can't suppose this.

Comment: My bad, you can't guarantee the existence of an isometric isomorphism (that would be absurd because otherwise I'd be able to conclude all norms come from an inner product). Instead, fix an isomorphism $T:V\to W$ (this will be a homeomorphism due to finite dimensionality). Now, consider the map between spheres $f: S_V\to S_W$ as $f(x) =\frac{T(x)}{\|T(x)\|_W}$, and argue why it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectlly.